# How to interpret an Alloy fact

Tags: alloy

I am reading [an article that uses Alloy to model some safety and security requirements for aircraft avionics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.1113.pdf). I am struggling to understand one of the "fact constraints" shown in the article.

Data flows into systems. Data is consumed by the systems. The model declares a set of Data, a set of System, and a consumedBy relation (Data is consumed by System):

```
sig Data {
   consumedBy: some System
} 

sig System {}
```

The model then declares a set of "criticality values." A relation maps criticality to data. Another relation maps criticality to system:

```
sig Criticality {
   concernedData: one Data, 
   concernedSystem: one System 
}
```

Next, the model expresses two facts. It's the second fact that I am struggling with.

The first fact says that each system consumes at least one datum:

```
all s: System | some consumedBy.s
```

The article has this comment about the second fact:

```
   // for any system which consumes a given datum,
   // the said datum and system should belong to
   // a same unique criticality
```

I think the comment is saying this: If a system consumes a datum, then the datum and the system must have the same criticality. For example, if datum D1 is consumed by system S1 and datum D1 has criticality C1, then system S1 must also have criticality C1. Do you agree with that interpretation of the comment?

Now, here is how the fact is expressed in Alloy:

```
   all d: Data | all s: System | one c: Criticality | 
      c.concernedData = d and c.concernedSystem = s
```

My understanding of how to read that fact is this:

```
The following constraint holds for exactly one c in Criticality:
    For every d in Data and every s in System:
        c.concernedData = d and c.concernedSystem = s
```

Is that a correct understanding of the fact? If so, I don't think the fact is expressing the same thing as the description in the comment.

So my questions are these:

One: the comment says this:

```
   // for any system which consumes a given datum,
   // the said datum and system should belong to
   // a same unique criticality
```

Does the following Alloy fact express the same thing as the comment?

```
   all d: Data | all s: System | one c: Criticality | 
      c.concernedData = d and c.concernedSystem = s
```

Two: if the comment and the Alloy fact are not the same, then what is the correct way to express the comment in Alloy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an Alloy model that compares the paper's version of the fact to what I believe captures what you want to express:

```
sig Data {consumedBy: some System}
sig Criticality {
   concernedData: one Data, 
   concernedSystem: one System 
}
sig System {} 

// the paper's statement:
// for any system which consumes a given datum,
// there is one criticality that has that data and system
// as its concernedData and concernedSystem
pred Paper {
  all d: Data | all s: d.consumedBy | one c: Criticality | 
      c.concernedData = d and c.concernedSystem = s
  }

// your interpretation:
//  If a system consumes a datum, then the datum and the system
// must have the same (single) criticality
pred You {
  all d: Data | all s: d.consumedBy | 
     concernedData.d = concernedSystem.s and one concernedSystem.s
  }

check {Paper implies You} for 2
```

If you execute this, you get the following counterexample that shows the difference between the two:

[image]

In short, the paper version says there is only one criticality shared by both; your version says that the datum and system are each associated with one criticality, and it's the same one (which is stronger).

I don't know which is right in this case.

The "one" quantifier, while having a very simple semantics ("one x: S | P" means P is true for one x in the set S) can be confusing because of how we're tempted to read quantifiers in natural language. There's a half page discussion of an example of this in the FAQ of Chapter 3 of Software Abstractions, on p.73.

Comment: Wow, awesome Daniel. Thank you very much!